# How to can make operator numbers in string as int in kotlin

Tags: java, string, intellij-idea, kotlin, int

I want to create operator in string and show the value as int.

// ex:

`val str= "1+2*3"`   , print out -> `"1+2*3"`

// i want:

print out -> `7`

however i tried to create kotlin code like:

`val str= "${1+2*3}"` or `val str= "1+2*3".toInt`

but all this don't work.

any help???

Comment: You're going to need some kind of a parser here. Btw, it's 7, not 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have some kind of parsers to achieve that.

Few examples

http://mathparser.org/

The advantage with the above is that you can perform any kind of calculation like below.

```
Expression e = new Expression("( 2 + 3/4 + sin(pi) )/2");
double v = e.calculate()
```

Or by using the Java inbuilt Scriptengine.

```
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
String foo = "1+2*3";
System.out.println(engine.eval(foo)); //prints 7
```